# server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Tags: php, apache, ssl, xampp, swiftmailer

Apache crashes with the following error

> [ssl:warn] [pid 6056:tid 408] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server
>   certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

when executing php script that send emails using Swiftmailer on localhost.

How to solve this issue ?

details: XAMPP v3.2.1 with PHP 5.6 , windows 8.1

Comment: create a matching certificate

Comment: Note: It's not an error, it's just a warning. You can safely ignore it. it is most certainly not the reason for a crash.

Comment: You can't ignore it. Regardless of whether it is or is not the cause of the problem, the server won't restart without fixing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps, I was getting the same error because I have docker started. The trick is to stop it and start apache first.

Comment: does not help i have no Docker